# How Do I Make Thumbnails Larger When Selecting Files For a File Input Type?

Tags: firefox

When selecting a file from the dialogue box that pops up for the "file" input type in Firefox, images are too small to be able to tell from the thumbnail what they are as shown below:

[image]

**Is there a way to change the view from a list view to a thumbnail view  so that I can easily see what the images are without having to know the name of the file I want to upload**, or is this a Firefox implementation issue? I have tried holding down ctrl and scrolling the mouse wheel but this doesn't work. One can click on each individual file to get a slightly larger thumbnail preview (I notice chromium's is a lot larger which is nicer), but this is very slow if you have hundreds of files in one directory.

Comment: An alternative "workaround" is to find the file you want using the file manager, and then drag it onto the filechooser dialog, which will select that particular file in the filechooser. Regarding the actual problem: it's kind of an oversight in firefox, in that Firefox doesn't actually request the thumbnails to be enabled in the chooser when opening it (whereas Chrome does), and I don't think there's really any fix for this, unfortunately.

Comment: I didn't know that one could drag and drop files into the file chooser dialogue, thats really neat and useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have selected a directory, the file chooser dialog doesn't know how to show a preview of a directory. But if you choose an image, it suddenly shows a preview on the right hand side.

Compare these two screenshots. One with a directory selected and another with an image selected.

Using Ubuntu 16.04

[image: Screenshot showing directory selected]

[image: Screenshot showing image file selected]